# WIX-Installer MSI Publisher Unknown

Tags: wix, installation

How to provide publisher Name for MSI installer which is developed using WIX Installer?

While installing my .msi installer it's showing unknown publisher, how to provide a name for publisher?Is it possible to do this within WIX? If so kindly help me how to implement this using WIX installer.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking to avoid the security warning that is displayed when someone installs your setup. For this you would need to sign the setup with your certificate and a private key. You can try to do this by following the steps explained in the following links:

- [How to Digitally Sign Microsoft Files](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/microsoft-digital-signatures/)
- [Signing .MSI and .EXE files](https://web.archive.org/web/20130916180154/http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/signing-msi-files)
- [Everything you need to know about Authenticode Code Signing](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204061212/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/22/authenticode-code-signing-for-developers-for-file-downloads-building-smartscreen-application-reputation.aspx)

<strike>Assuming you are looking for a publisher name in the control panel `Programs and Features`. You could use the `Manufacturer` attribute in your `Product` tag.</strike>

```
<Product Id="PUT-YOUR-GUID"  
 Manufacturer="PublisherName" 
 Name="ProductName" 
 UpgradeCode="PUT-YOUR-GUID" 
 Version="1.0.0">
```

Comment: Actually the Manufacturer attribute is already provided inside my Product tag. What is happening when i run my msi at that time it will show below unknow publisher.

Comment: Looks like the second link is dead.

Comment: @Crono that's true and unfortunately I can't find the original now. It's strange a company like intel would remove their blogs/articles...

Answer (score 8):

Using WiX's in-built tool `insignia` is fairly straight-forward. Here's the steps to do code-sign a WiX MSI:

1. Add `signtool` to my PATH. It is commonly found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64` or, more recently, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit`
2. Add `insignia` to my PATH. Your `WiX Toolset` directory is commonly found at
   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin"`
3. Sign my MSI in a post-build event (MSI Project -> Properties -> Build Events) by calling this:
   `signtool sign /f "c:\certificates\mycert.pfx" /p cert-password /d "Your Installer Label" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /v $(TargetFileName)`

---

Further notes and thoughts:

- I have also signed the application (I think) by just doing `Project Properties -> Signing` and enabling click-once manifests, selecting
  the certificate and checking the `Sign the assembly` option.
- Here's my similar answer on how to do the same but for a bootstrap bundle: [using insignia to sign WiX MSI and bootstrap bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748646/865643)

Comment: Does the consumer of my .msi installer file need to install my certificate authority that I used to generate the signing certificate?