# How to get correct FrameworkSDKPath in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to get my WiX bootstrap installer signed in Visual Studio.  I am following example shown in [WiX: Digitally Sign BootStrapper project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381525/wix-digitally-sign-bootstrapper-project)

Unfortunately had to use explicit path to sign tool to get it to work...

```
  <Target Name="UsesFrameworkSdk">
    <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
      <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="FrameworkSdkPath" />
    </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
    <Message Text="SDK path = '$(FrameworkSdkPath)'" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="UsesSignTool" DependsOnTargets="UsesFrameworkSdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SignToolPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe</SignToolPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

The FrameworkSdkPath variable returns "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\" which is not where the sign tool is.

If I start a VS command tool the environment variable WindowsSdkDir is set to the the directory containing signtool.exe.  However this variable is not set within Visual Studio.

How to do this properly so I don't have to set explicit path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to do this properly so I don't have to set explicit path?

From the example, we could get the path from registry. like this:

```
 <Target Name="UsesFrameworkSdk">
    <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
      <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="FrameworkSdkPath" />
    </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Win10SDK>$(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0@InstallationFolder)</Win10SDK>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="SDK path = '$(Win10SDK)'" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="UsesSignTool" DependsOnTargets="UsesFrameworkSdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SignToolPath Condition="('@(SignToolPath)'=='') and Exists('$(Win10SDK)\bin\x86\signtool.exe')">$(Win10SDK)\bin\x86\signtool.exe</SignToolPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is no longer valid for most recent versions of the SDK because the bin folder has moved.  Here is the correction:

```
<Target Name="UsesFrameworkSdk">
  <PropertyGroup>

<Win10SDKBinPath>$(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0@InstallationFolder)bin\</Win10SDKBinPath>

<Win10SDKVersion>$(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0@ProductVersion).0\</Win10SDKVersion>
      <Win10SDKVerBinPath>$(Win10SDKBinPath)$(Win10SDKVersion)
    </Win10SDKVerBinPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="UsesSignTool" DependsOnTargets="UsesFrameworkSdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignToolPath Condition="('@(SignToolPath)'=='') and Exists('$(Win10SDKVerBinPath)x86\signtool.exe')">$(Win10SDKVerBinPath)x86\signtool.exe</SignToolPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```