# WIX-Installer : Digitally signed Bootstapper exe failing to install

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installation, digital-signature

I am unable to proceed with the installation using digitally signed WIX installer bootstrapped exe.

Below is log extract highlighting the issue.

[39B8:26D4][2017-09-04T20:03:31]i371: Updating registry key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{c6dca553-993e-473c-be4b-8ffa184cd19f}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No

[3904:3A84][2017-09-04T20:03:31]i336: Acquiring container: WixAttachedContainer, copy from: F:\Digital Signature\MyApp.exe

[3904:3A84][2017-09-04T20:03:31]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'F:\Digital Signature\'

[3904:19F4][2017-09-04T20:03:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to extract all files from container, erf: 1:2:0

[3904:3A84][2017-09-04T20:03:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to wait for operation complete.

[3904:3A84][2017-09-04T20:03:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to open container.

[3904:3A84][2017-09-04T20:03:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to open container: WixAttachedContainer.

[3904:3A84][2017-09-04T20:03:31]e312: Failed to extract payloads from container: WixAttachedContainer to working path: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp{18826196-247C-4057-B849-948AF1A2A7E5}\14B0A9896E9807C47A99BA7BF6B295B54ACE22FD, error: 0x80070001.

[3904:39A4][2017-09-04T20:03:31]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed while caching, aborting execution.

[39B8:26D4][2017-09-04T20:03:31]i372: Registry key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{c6dca553-993e-473c-be4b-8ffa184cd19f}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No

[39B8:26D4][2017-09-04T20:03:31]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {c6dca553-993e-473c-be4b-8ffa184cd19f}

[39B8:26D4][2017-09-04T20:03:31]i352: Removing cached bundle: {c6dca553-993e-473c-be4b-8ffa184cd19f}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{c6dca553-993e-473c-be4b-8ffa184cd19f}\

I am able to install with WIX non-signed boot strapping exe.
What is the problem with digitally signed bootstrapper?
Please let me know if anyone had similar issue and solution to address it.

Comment: Signing a bottstrapper is tricky - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20474482/600559

Comment: Thanks, Morten. Very useful link that may solve our problem, I am trying it.

Comment: Is this the same issue? [Wix bootstrap exe giving error when digitally signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041168/wix-bootstrap-exe-giving-error-when-digitally-signed). Since there is no accepted answer anywhere it can't be set duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WiX: Digitally Sign BootStrapper project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381525/wix-digitally-sign-bootstrapper-project)