# how to Sign installer using EV Code Signing

Tags: winforms, installshield, code-signing, burn

I have a code signing certificate for my application and also created a setup using Install Shield. Now my question is that can i sign the Whole setup at once or just sign Exe file present in the Bin of the project also If i have a Wix installer as well so how can i sign this installer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you enable [digital signing in IS](https://docs.flexera.com/isxhelp22/helplibrary/SigningFiles.htm).

This is how you can do it with Wix: 
[WiX: Digitally Sign BootStrapper project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381525/wix-digitally-sign-bootstrapper-project)

This is how you can do it from the command line, no matter what tool you are using to build your setup:

[- Using SignTool to Sign a File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/using-signtool-to-sign-a-file)